# Which documents are required to enter Maldives from India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork, maldives

I am planning to travel to the Maldives from India from 30th July till 6th August. I want to ask what all documents are required besides Passport to enter the Maldives?

I am a citizen of India. I will be flying from Mumbai, Maharashtra.

Comment: What research have you done so far? Eg have you tried searching Maldives immigration web site for the info you need?